# Yii Captcha don't refresh image on refresh button clicked

Tags: yii, captcha

I don't know why my Captcha image do not refresh when i click on refresh link.

My code is :

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
```

I saw XHR response , it was empty and i checked the link of the refresh link , some thing like tis :

> mydomain/captcha?refresh=1&_=1367673730496

and it return an image but it should return somthing like

> {"hash1":311,"hash2":311,"url":"/mydomain/captcha?v=518509b295d06"}

- I saw above link in the other application of mine which works fine with CCaptch.
- On page refresh , Captcha image changes.

The corrupted captcha sent one XHR , the refresh one but the fine Captcha should send two as i saw in the other application,one for refresh and other for getting image.

What should i do ?

**Edit:**

I found another fact :

functional Captcha works with jquery.min but corrupted one works with jquery !! but i don't add anything to header , they added by Yii.

**Second Edition:**

I found two files which handle captcha in yii framework and i see when i send this request :

> mydonmain/controller/captcha?refresh=1

And get

```
print_r($_GET);
die();
```

it return :

> Array ( [/controller/captcha] => )

which means it don't understand get->refresh request !! somehow the $_GET request is disabled !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you checked Yii main.php which contain urlManager section ? the rules are sequential.